# validate error message not displaying for drop down list when not selected

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Please bear with me as I am not sure what I have done wrong here:

Basically I have a form and I have some drop down lists.

If I hard code the `select list` for my drop down list with `styleClass="requiredinpfield"` then I will get a proper validation error message pops up below the `select list` whenever I don't select an option from the list and if I try hit submit button.

However, because some of the drop down lists are not always required (they only required when certain option was selected) so in this case I am not hard coding these select lists to have `styleClass="requiredinpfield"` but instead I am using `jQuery` to dynamically add the `requiredinpfield` class to the list object whenever an associate radio button was selected.

The problem I am having now is this won't show the validation error message when I don't select any option and try to hit the Submit button. It prevent me from continue, however. Its just I don't get to see the error message. Can you see what I have done wrong?

Here is an example of how I use jQuery to add the `requiredinpfield` class and it is not showing me the validation error message when needed:

**HTML**

```
<div id="fruitDivId">
    <apex:inputField id="testPickList" value="{!PickTheFruitYouLike__c}" styleClass="selectpicker"/>
</div>
```

**A radio button to confirm that the list is needed**

```
<apex:selectRadio value="{!DoYouLikeFruit}" onchange="whenAnOptionWasSelectedAndINeedToAddRequiredInpField(this.value,'fruitDivId');" styleClass="requiredinpfield radio pa-cus pa-cus-other">
```

**Script to add `requiredinpfield` class**

```
function whenAnOptionWasSelectedAndINeedToAddRequiredInpField(t,divId)
{
    if (t == 'Yes' ){
        $('[id$='+divId+']').show();
        $('[id$="testPickList"]').addClass('requiredinpfield');
    }
    else{
        $('[id$='+divId+']').hide();
        $('[id$="testPickList"]').removeClass('requiredinpfield');
    }     
}
```

**Script to validate**

Note: my submit button will trigger the !checkRequired() method.

```
 function checkRequired(){
    var isValidate = true;
    //$('.errorIcon').css('opacity', '0');
    $('.requiredinpfield').each(function(){
        if($(this).is("select") && $(this).val() == ''){
            /*alert("Hello!!");*/
            if(!($(this).next('.requiredinpfield').first().next('.errorMsg').size()>0)){
                console.log($(this).next('.requiredinpfield'));
                $(this).next('.requiredinpfield').first().after('<div class="errorMsg"><strong></strong> You must select an option</div>');
            }
            isValidate = false;
        }
    else{

        if($(this).is("select") && (($(this).next('.requiredinpfield').first().next('.errorMsg').size()>0)))
        {
            $(this).next('.requiredinpfield').first().next('.errorMsg').remove();
        }
    }
    });
    //alert(isValidate);
    return isValidate;
}
```

Comment: What library/framework you using? `apex` ain't no tag I ever heard of!

Comment: This is from a Salesforce visual force page

Comment: by any chance you have any thought?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the rest of the code is correct, the problem might in the way you are selecting elements by ID

in jQuery, to select an element by id simply write

```
$('#idoftheelement')
```

so in your `whenAnOptionWasSelectedAndINeedToAddRequiredInpField` function,
try replacing

```
$('[id$='+divId+']')
```

with

```
$('#'+divId)
```

do the same at all locations where you are selecting by id.

Comment: my `div` is showing and hiding fine. I don't see why I need to change that line?